# How to get a subset of teradata table i.e. from nth row to n+3th row values

Tags: multithreading, teradata

Assume I have a table A with 100 records in it in Teradata. Now I have to pass 20-20 rows 5 times to a specific process. I am struggling to segment that whole table with 100 records into 5 subparts, any clue of any SQL which can give me such data.

Example:

```
table A

A   AA
B   BB
C   CC
D   DD
E   EE
F   FF
```

Here I have 6 records, I want to fetch first 2 and then second 2 and then last 2 records one by one, any SQL help

Answer (score 0):

If there's some unique column(s) you can apply ROW_NUMBERs:

```
select *
from table
QUALIFY
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY unique_column(s)) BETWEEN 3 AND 4
;
```

Of course, this is not very efficient on a big table.